# How to add both character encoding and the attachment for response?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, jax-rs

I have a requirement to set both character encoding and the attachment for the responseheader
during file download. How can I do that?

```
ResponseBuilder lResBuild = Response.ok(lResult);
lResBuild.type("application/vnd.ms-excel");
lResBuild.header("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-16LE");
lResponse = lResBuild.build();
lResponse = Response.ok(lResponse).header("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename = " + lFileName + ".xls").build();
```

Something like this. For special characters I am getting underscore.

Comment: Do you mean you have underscore in filename or in entity body?

Comment: @MichalGajdos i have underscore in Filename which has ISO format date appended to it.